# i cant access my web app from a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i have my web app created using react inside a container and its running smoothly but when i want to access the localhost after binding contaienr port to mine its doesnt work but if i run the app without docker its working fine

this is he **dockerfile ** [image]
**
container logs **
[image]

docker build -t my-react-app .

docker run --name test -p 80:5173 my-react-app

Comment: Containers are their own host. You can't communicate to a container that only binds to the loop back interface. You need to use the private network interface inside the container or more easy 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Please replace the dockerfile image with the code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

The app is only accessible from within the container itself, not from the host machine. This is because localhost refers to the loopback interface, which is only accessible from within the container.

If you want to make the app accessible from the host machine, you need to set the HOST environment variable to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. This tells the app to listen on all available network interfaces, including the loopback interface.

You can set the HOST environment variable to 0.0.0.0 in your Dockerfile like this:

```
# set the host
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

# run the app
CMD ["npm", "dev"]
```

Then, when you run the container, you can bind it to a specific host and port using the -p flag. This will start the React app and bind it to the host's port you specified, so you should be able to access it from your host machine by visiting http://localhost:5173 in your web browser.